# Compare 2 files and delete the lines that match criteria using awk / sed /bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am new to awk and sed and have the below requirement.

Below is the file data

Old File :

```
SNO,ID,SHAPE,COST,CURRENTCOST
1,ABC,EFG,123,123
2,EEC,EFG,123,12
3,ARR,EFG,123,12
```

New File :

```
SNO,ID,SHAPE,COST,CURRENTCOST
1,ABC,EFG,123,0
2,EEC,EFG,123,12
3,ARR,EFG,123,12
```

Expected output File :

```
SNO,ID,SHAPE,COST,CURRENTCOST
2,EEC,EFG,123,12
3,ARR,EFG,123,12
```

Firstly , I would like compare the ID's and if they match CHECK IF CURRENTCOST(5th Column ) is 0 , if it is 0 , then delete the line from New file

Below is the code flow

```
if(CURRENTCOST == 0)
THEN 
  IF(FIRST FILE ID == SECOND FILE ID)
     THEN DELETE THE LINE FROM SECOND FILE 
  ELSE
     DO NOTHING
```

Also , I can skip copying that line if the condition is true and copy other lines to a new file

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk -F, 'NR == FNR {a[$1]=$5; next} !($1 in a && $5 == 0)' oldFile newFile

SNO,ID,SHAPE,COST,CURRENTCOST
2,EEC,EFG,123,12
3,ARR,EFG,123,12
```

Comment: Can you please explain it ?

Comment: I will add explanation but this is fairly simple 2 file awk command. Did this really work?

Comment: Yes , I see we are adding the 5th column in a data structure and checking if column 1 matched with file2 s column 1, what if the files are unsorted, does it make solution  more complicated

Comment: Or we have to sort them before running awk,

Comment: If you add these new example data with expected output in your question then I can try to tweak my awk command

Comment: Thanks , will do , initially all my files are sorted and this works . Or I can have a pipe and sort command

Comment: Also to let you know sort order of files doesn't matter for this awk command to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v '0$' newFile  | join -t , -o 2.{1..5} oldFile -
```

1. remove the unwanted line from the newFile
2. join oldfile with modified content from stdin
3. select columns from newfile only